# Venturing out of group during internship?

Tags: internship, software

I'm working at a big software company in a group I'm not happy with. My internship ends and I know this will be my last opportunity to keep myself alive in this company (presence wise). I have potential networking ops to work on projects outside of this group. Does it make me look bad if I take on a different project for a different group to maybe find a niche I'm more interested in with people I can better identify with?  Is there a "correct" way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does it make me look bad if I take on a different project for a
>   different group to maybe find a niche I'm more interested in with
>   people I can better identify with?

**No, it doesn't make you look bad.** This is what internships are for.

Internships should be a time for exploring and learning as much as you can, for trying out different roles to see what might fit the best, and for learning what the working world is about.

Nobody will feel bad if your first shot wasn't a keeper.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you're professional in how you approach it there is nothing wrong with exploring. Some companies like when employees show interest in other areas of the business. It shows a willingness to be adaptable and cross train in other functions/departments. In the area of software it's very good for skill development and professional growth to understand other functions like QA or front-end design as opposed to just staying in your primary area of skill.

Comment: Great, thanks. What's a good way to ask for such?

Comment: Go to your manager and/or the manager of the area you want to cross train in and ask if there is the possibility that you can shadow a developer in that are because you want to learn how your primary and secondary area (the one you want to cross into) tie into each other. As long as you're not showing a lack of interest in the primary area of your internship while wanting to cross over, you should be fine.